# Everyone suddenly started ignoring me!

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, manager

I had some problems with my manager that she refused to discuss, so I decided to stop trying. Due to the nature of my work, I had to travel to another country. I left in good terms with everyone, I even tried to get to my manager to say goodbye, but she said that she had meetings. Anyway, I have not done anything wrong since I haven't seen my coworkers since then. Minding my own business in the new country, I suddenly, found myself deleted from my workplace email. I found that someone has criticized my manager in a survey for employees satisfaction, so she deleted me.

I needed some help with some issues I am facing, and the employee responsible keeps ignoring my messages (they answer with generic answers or give no answer at all). I soon became aware that all of my colleagues do not want to give me a hand for no clear reason! They all give generic answers or no answers at all. Even those who I had good relationship with. I don't know what to do.

*By the way, my manager wronged me. This is why we got in trouble, but it is a long story and I felt it would take a lot of time.

Comment: It is a feature where all the staff members' emails are put at one group. So when you want to send an email, you don't have to go through the staff members one by one. You just send to the group and the email will be sent to everyone. I was deleted from the group.

Comment: "Everyone is ignoring me ... you are closed" is an odd reaction :-) To me this is a legal question.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes.

Comment: "I suddenly, found myself deleted from my workplace email." - You should edit your question to clarify what this means exactly.  If you are no longer part of a specific work group, removing an old team member, makes complete sense.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know whether your colleagues were instructed not to answer to your questions. If they were forced to do, they'd probably do so because practically they can't stand by you and put their job under risk. So we can't blame them.

I think it is better to speak directly to your manager or Director regarding this. Speak to them gently and tell them about your problem.

Comment: I tried to talks to my manager twice before I travel. She was not reaponsive

Comment: That's why I've mentioned Manager or Director. If the manager isn't responsive, speak to the higher officials like the Director

Comment: I thought about it. I am considering this seriously now, but honestly, I am afraid that my manager will use her power against me later.

Comment: But we need the problem to get sorted. As the colleagues aren't responding properly, it'd be better to communicate with higher officials. Tell them only about your problems and try not to include anything about your manager in the conversation.

Comment: @Basha doing nothing will only let the problem get worse